# Capture data between Application and Printer driver

Tags: printing, windows-xp, driver, virtual

We are in the process of developing app for an POS(point of sale) system in which we need to design some kind of driver to capture the data that is going for print. We need to develop specifically the driver to capture the data between POS application and printer device driver. If anybody can provide some idea as to how to approach to this problem.

Is it possible with virtual driver to extract data to text file then print the document ?